# Jquery horizontal scroller like that?

Tags: jquery, scroller

I was wondering if it was possible to recreate an horizontal scrolling effect with mouse click control like this
http://www.lazzarionline.com/collections.php

Thank you so much,
I search a lot but I didn't find something like that gallery
Luca

Comment: http://www.lazzarionline.com/js/scroller.js

Comment: It doesn't mean he is allowed to use it, some developers care about such things.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make something draggable, that's quite easy with jQuery, it's something like `$("#someComponent").draggable();` (you'd better google that first). But you gave the answer yourself, you found a site where this horizontal slider is, so look at the source and copy-paste. **Stackoverflow is not there to write code for you.**

Comment: @j08691 gave the exact location already, just copy and paste (or if you are working on a big project that many people are going to know about, look at the code and write something similar, for the reason Peter pointed out).